# Integration tests for an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web API are always running in "Development" mode

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, azure-devops

I wanted to learn how to create an API which involves `ASP.NET Core API 2.1 + Dapper + DbUp + Azure Key Vault` and hosted inside of an `Azure App Service (Web App)` and also to manage it inside an `Azure DevOps project with CI/CD`.

I am using 2 environments (Development and Production) and in the `Azure App Service (Web App)` where I deploy this, I have set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` with a value set for **Production**

In Azure DevOps I chose the `ASP.NET Core Template` for my build pipeline (I am using the designer not the YAML) and, I am facing an issue when running the "tests".

[image: The error in build pipeline]

The tests I have implemented are "integration tests" and they always run in the `Development` environment. To resolve this I implemented a custom `WebApplicationFactory` as instructed in the below references,

- https://holsson.wordpress.com/2018/06/25/integration-testing-asp-net-core-2-1/
  (this has a link to github where the issue and the suggested approach has been given)

Will you able to help me resolve the issue please?

The code snippets in my application are provided below.

- **appsettings.Development.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "DatabaseConfig": {
    "ConnectionString": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=BlogDb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;"
  }
}
```

- **appsettings.Production.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AzureKeyVaultUrl": "THE AKV URL",
  "DatabaseConfig": {
    "ConnectionString": "BlogConnectionString"
  }
}
```

- My database settings are in a class `DatabaseConfig` and in NON development mode it will use `AKV` to get the connection string data.

So in **Program.cs**

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
        {
            if (!context.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                var akvUrl = builder.Build()[AzureKeyVaultUrl];
                var tokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
                var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(tokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

                builder.AddAzureKeyVault(akvUrl, keyVaultClient, new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
            }
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

**In `Startup.cs`**

```
public void ConfigureDevelopmentServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    RegisterDevDepdendencies(services);
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}

public void ConfigureProductionServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    RegisterDependencies(services);
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}

private void RegisterDevDepdendencies(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //
    // Register configurations
    //
    services.Configure<DatabaseConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseConfig"));
    services.AddSingleton(provider =>
    {
        var dbConfig = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<DatabaseConfig>>().Value;
        return dbConfig;
    });
    //
    // Register repositories
    //
    services.AddTransient<IPostsRepository, PostsRepository>();
    //
    // Register filters
    //
    services.AddTransient<IStartupFilter, DevDatabaseInitFilter>();
}

private void RegisterDependencies(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //
    // Register configurations
    //
    services.Configure<DatabaseConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("DatabaseConfig"));
    services.AddSingleton(provider =>
    {
        var dbConfig = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<DatabaseConfig>>().Value;
        var connectionString = Configuration[dbConfig.ConnectionString];
        return new DatabaseConfig {ConnectionString = connectionString};
    });
    //
    // Register repositories
    //
    services.AddTransient<IPostsRepository, PostsRepository>();
    //
    // Register filters
    //
    services.AddTransient<IStartupFilter, DatabaseInitFilter>();
}
```

***The startup filter implementations***

The startup filters are to do migrations using DbUp. I am running this as a startup task (this was inspired after reading the awesome article from ***Andrew Lock***). Below are their implementations.

```
public class DevDatabaseInitFilter : IStartupFilter
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DevDatabaseInitFilter(DatabaseConfig config)
    {
        _connectionString = config?.ConnectionString;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_connectionString))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));
        }
    }

    public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
    {
        EnsureDatabase.For.SqlDatabase(_connectionString);

        var dbUpgradeEngineBuilder = DeployChanges.To
            .SqlDatabase(_connectionString)
            .WithScriptsEmbeddedInAssembly(typeof(DatabaseInitFilter).Assembly)
            .WithTransaction()
            .LogToAutodetectedLog();

        var dbUpgradeEngine = dbUpgradeEngineBuilder.Build();

        if (dbUpgradeEngine.IsUpgradeRequired())
        {
            var upgradeOperation = dbUpgradeEngine.PerformUpgrade();
            if (!upgradeOperation.Successful)
            {
                throw new Exception("Database upgrade unsuccessful", upgradeOperation.Error);
            }
        }

        return next;
    }
}

public class DatabaseInitFilter : IStartupFilter
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DatabaseInitFilter(DatabaseConfig config)
    {   
        _connectionString = config?.ConnectionString;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_connectionString))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));
        }
    }

    public Action<IApplicationBuilder> Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> next)
    {
        EnsureDatabase.For.SqlDatabase(_connectionString);

        var dbUpgradeEngineBuilder = DeployChanges.To
            .SqlDatabase(_connectionString)
            .WithScriptsEmbeddedInAssembly(typeof(DatabaseInitFilter).Assembly)
            .WithTransaction()
            .LogToAutodetectedLog();

        var dbUpgradeEngine = dbUpgradeEngineBuilder.Build();

        if (dbUpgradeEngine.IsUpgradeRequired())
        {
            var upgradeOperation = dbUpgradeEngine.PerformUpgrade();
            if (!upgradeOperation.Successful)
            {
                throw new Exception("Database upgrade unsuccessful", upgradeOperation.Error);
            }
        }

        return next;
    }
}
```

**And finally, the test related classes**

```
public class TestWebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> : WebApplicationFactory<TEntryPoint> where TEntryPoint : class
{
    private const string AspNetCoreEnvironment = "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT";

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);

        var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(AspNetCoreEnvironment);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(env))
        {
            builder.UseEnvironment(env);
        }
    }
}

public class PostsControllerTests : IClassFixture<TestWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private HttpClient _client;

    public PostsControllerTests(TestWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _client = factory.CreateClient();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task Must_Have_Posts()
    {

        //
        // Arrange and Act
        //
        var httpResponse = await _client.GetAsync(@"/api/posts").ConfigureAwait(false);
        //
        // Assert
        //
        httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: I even tried creating 2 pipelines for `Development` and for `Production`. In `Development` I removed the "test" task in `Development` but kept it in the `Production` mode and, still I face the same problem. 

Even on the `Production` the tests fallbacks to **Development** mode.

Comment: well, the most obvious question, could you debug and see what's the value of the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` while running the tests?  Is this `ConfigureWebHost` being called? Put some logging so you can see what's going on..

Comment: You can set build variables as well, so try setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in your build pipeline.

Comment: Hi @jpgrassi thanks. I did debug and ‘Environment.GetVariable(“ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT”) gives me null when I am debugging regardless of the value which i set in the API project.

Comment: I will try the build variables. If I understood what you meant by that when running tests to pass that variable. As per my knowledge you cant do that (dotnet test) ?

Comment: The environment variable is set on the machine. You can set the variable in the command line profile you are running, like bash or powershell. But the fact that during debug you have it null is already problematic. During debug it should be Development